# Angular JS ng-pageslide not masking the parent window

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using ng-pageslide directive to implement the page slide.I have tried lots of ways to mask the parent page so that it will get look of pop up but feel of sliding.

is there any possible way to mask the parent window so that nothing is clickable from the parent page unless until the slide is closed.

please help me out..

Answer (score 0):

Not without modifying ng-pageslide.

What you could do is append another div to the body(https://github.com/dpiccone/ng-pageslide/blob/master/src/angular-pageslide-directive.js#L81) that would be transparent and absolutely positioned, but with zindex sligtly lower than the slide have, which is 1000.

Comment: can you give some example in fiddle? i have tried to add one more div but no luck